# Why does referencing break when done through pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, class-design

i have a referenced default constructor for a class test.

```
class test {
public:
    test(int &input1) : int_test(input1) {};
    ~test() {};

    int & int_test; 
};
```

Then 2 more classes which interact with test as follows:

```
class notebook
{ 
public:
    notebook() {};
    ~notebook() {};

    int int_notebook;
};

class factory
{
public: 
    factory() {};
    ~factory(){};

    notebook *p_notebook;
};
```

If i intitalise test (t2) with an integer, this works as expected:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

    int var=90;
    test t2(var);
    cout<<t2.int_test; // this gives 90
    var=30;
    cout<<t2.int_test; // this gives 30
```

Once i initialised the test class with a pointer to a member of class notebook through a third class factory:

```
factory f1;
notebook s1;
notebook s2;
s1.int_notebook=10;
s2.int_notebook=2;

int notebook::*p_notebook= &notebook::int_notebook;
f1.p_notebook=&s1;

test t1(((f1.p_notebook->*p_notebook)));
cout<<t1.int_test; // This gives  10
```

however if i change the pointer of f1.p_notebook to another object of notebook s2;

```
f1.p_notebook=&s2;
cout<<t1.int_test; // This gives  10
```

the reference member of a of t1 (t1.int_test) doesnt reflect the change of the pointer. could some one explain to me why ? or what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Sorry but... what? This is a mess. Make a clean, tidy, tiny testcase please.

Comment: I resubmitted with a simpler code!

Comment: Even after being properly formatted, that isn't nice code. Should clue you in that something is suboptimal.

Comment: thank you for the tip. I tried to make as compact as possible but it seems it was difficult for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CTester
{
    public:
        CTester(int &input1) : int_test(input1)
        {
            std::cout << int_test << std::endl;
        }
        int &int_test;
};

class notebook
{
    public:
        int int_notebook;
};

class factory
{
    public:
        notebook *p_notebook;
};

int main()
{
    factory f1;
    notebook s1;
    notebook s2;
    s1.int_notebook=10;
    s2.int_notebook=2;

    int notebook::*p_notebook = &notebook::int_notebook;
    f1.p_notebook=&s1;
    CTester t1(f1.p_notebook->*p_notebook);
    f1.p_notebook=&s2;
    CTester t2(f1.p_notebook->*p_notebook);

    return 0;
}
```

this prints

```
10
2
```

Comment: This is not what i'm after. The constructor of class tester is reference to int_tester. If i understand correctly  i dont need to reinitialise the default constructor twice to change the value of int_test from 10 to 2 if i had initiated with a interger rather than a pointer to integer. for example. int var=90;test t2(var); var=30; in this case t2.int_test will give 2 but this is not the case when i initiated the constructor with a pointer to an integer.

Comment: No. The f1.p_notebook->*p_notebook expression will be evaluate to &s1.int_notebook at constructor call, and that pointer will be passed to the contrucor

Comment: but but the constructor is passed to &int_test which is a reference . so why does it work in the first example and fails in the second! please have another look above as i added to the code to see what i'm talking about.

Comment: I can repeat myself f1.p_notebook->*p_notebook expression will be evaluate to s1.int_notebook so test t1(f1.p_notebook->*p_notebook); equivalent to test t1(s1.int_notebook);

Comment: how can i change t1.int_test by changing the address of f1.p_notebook?

Comment: Also what is the difference between declaring int int_test by removing the reference operand as opposed to int &int_test then.

Comment: C++ is not a functional language. C++ just executes the commands but you started to tells to the C++ that what is the relationship between your objects. So if your reference to a notbook is in a factory object, than you have to pass it to CTester. C++ just wants to know what to execute

Answer (score 0):

Your class `test` has a reference to an int.  It doesn't know anything about what object that int actually belongs to.  Or how it originally got access to that int.  Let's break down this line of code:

```
test t1(((f1.p_notebook->*p_notebook)));
```

First this:

```
f1.p_notebook
```

As of that line, it is a pointer to s1.  Now this:

```
f1.p_notebook->*p_notebook
```

That's s1's `int_notebook` member.  So with this:

```
test t1(((f1.p_notebook->*p_notebook)));
```

You are passing s1's `int_notebook` member to the constructor of test.  So now the object `t1` has a reference to s1's `int_notebook` member.  It does not care about the obscure levels of indirection you used to get that member.  It[t1] knows nothing of f1, or f1.p_notebook.  So when you do this:

```
f1.p_notebook=&s2;
```

That has absolutely no effect on s1.int_notebook, and therefore it has no effect on t1's reference member.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. this is much clearer now you have explained. I managed to get there by declaring a reference to class notebook and changing it accordingly to manipulate int_test. Which is working fine. However, it seems that this solution if you are working on the heap but i shall do it another posting. THank you so much again.